# Getting wrong path of xml file after installing windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written the below code to load xml file.

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\Configurations.xml");
```

It is working fine if I am debugging the code using Visual Studio, however after installation it is finding the file at this location

`Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\Configurations.xml'.`

How to resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Services are started with [Service Control Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685150(VS.85).aspx) so the directory is `%WinDir%\System32` or `%WinDir%\SysWOW64`.

The most appropriate directory path would be
[AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the name of the directory containing the application.

You can access this information for the current domain with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase` expression.